# Flutter Widget Testing - Hive setup for testing

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-development, flutter-hive

I'm facing an issue while running widget tests for my Flutter app that uses Hive for local storage. I keep getting the error message: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider).

I have found some info that said Hive is being initialised before the flutter engine and to use: WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(), to solve the issue. This causes the test to run until it times out.

Here's a simplified version of my test setup:

I have a hive_setup.dart file where I initialize Hive for testing using Hive.init() and open boxes.
In my widget test file, I use setUp to initialize Hive and tearDown to close it after each test case.

The screen I am trying to test is a from which uses data stored in hive to display dropdown options. The functionality of the form widgets is what I am trying to test.

Can someone please help me figure out what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Is there something I'm missing in my testing setup?

Here's my code for reference:

hive_setup.dart:

```
import 'package:dps_app/common/common.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> initializeHiveForTesting() async {
  final testHivePath = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  Hive
    ..init(testHivePath.path)
    ..registerAdapter(ImageToUploadModelAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<dynamic>('settings');
  await Hive.openBox<ImageToUploadModel>(tempImagesBoxKey);
}

Future<void> closeHiveForTesting() async {
  await Hive.close();
}
```

Widget test file:

```
import 'package:dps_app/features/patients/patients.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'hive_setup.dart';

void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  late ProviderContainer container;

  setUp(() async {
    container = ProviderContainer(); // Create a new container for each test group
    await initializeHiveForTesting();
  });

  tearDown(() async {
    container.dispose(); // Dispose of the container after each test group
    await closeHiveForTesting();
  });
  group('PatientAdd Widget Tests', () {
    testWidgets('Form Validation - Valid Input', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        const ProviderScope(
          // parent: container,
          child: PatientAdd(),
        ),
      );
      // await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.byKey(const Key('firstName')), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution. I have used the *integration_test* package of flutter instead and added the full app initialization steps to the setup method before tests are run. The init steps were present before my **runApp(myApp)** function which is why Hive and other components failed at the start of the test.